# Arithmetic in Prolog - Multiples of a number

Tags: list, prolog, arithmetic-expressions

I want to create a function `multiples(X, N, R)` where `R` is a list containing all multiples of `X` from `X` to `X * N`.

An example would be: `multiples(3, 4, [12, 9, 6, 3])`, which should give out true.

My code so far:

```
multiples(X, N, R) :- X >= 1, N >= 1, Z is X*N, contains(Z, R).

contains(Z, [Z|_]).
contains(Z, [W|V]) :- contains(Z,V), L is Z-X, L >= X, contains(L, V).
```

The output of the console for `multiples(3,4,X).` is `X = [12|_xxxx]` and when I type `;` an error occurs.
How do I manage to receive the list that I want?
(Maybe my idea is completely wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 4 issues with your code. Here is the fixed code, explanation below:

```
multiples(X, N, R) :- 
    X >= 1, 
    N >= 1, 
    Z is X*N, 
    contains(X, Z, R).

contains(X, Z, [Z|V]) :- 
    L is Z-X, 
    L >= X, 
    contains(X, L, V).
contains(_, Z, [Z]).

?- multiples(3,4,X).
X = [12, 9, 6, 3] ;
X = [12, 9, 6] ;
X = [12, 9] ;
X = [12] ;
false.
```

At first in your `contains` predicate you access `X` and `W` and never state their values. Solve `X` by adding another attribute to the predicate. Solve `W` by replacing it with `Z`.

Another problem is the order of your rules. The larger `contains` rule should be the "main" rule, only if this one fails the other one should "fire". By placing the default rule on top you get the right result.

Also the rule `contains(_, Z, [Z]).` marks the end, therefore it the return list has only the element `Z` in it and does not contain any other (unknown) elements.

The last point is that you don't need two `contains` calls in the main `contains` rule.

The example works for the first answer. However you can improve this with a cut (`!`), which prevents going to the second rule after successfully visiting the first rule:

```
contains(X, Z, [Z|V]) :- 
    L is Z-X, 
    L >= X, 
    !,
    contains(X, L, V).
contains(_, Z, [Z]).

?- multiples(3,4,X).
X = [12, 9, 6, 3].
```

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer! Now I understand what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your code. `contains predicate` will collect the numbers in a list, and N will keep getting decreased till it satisfies the base predicate.

```
multiples(X, N, R) :- X >= 1, N >= 1, contains(X,N, R),!.

contains(_,0,[]).
contains(X,N,[Z|List]):-
    Z is X*N,
    N1 is N-1,
    contains(X,N1,List).
```

**Example:**

```
?- multiples(3,4,R).
R = [12, 9, 6, 3]

?- multiples(2,5,R).
R = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

?- multiples(25,5,R).
R = [125, 100, 75, 50, 25]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possible way for removing the "!" without the second answer resulting in an endless loop, just curious.

Comment: Yes, remove it from the multiples predicate and add it to contains ( contains(_,0,[]):-!.)